# FullCalendar not showing extraParams

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am having some problems retrieving these from my string

here is my script, taken from the website..

```
  events: {
            url: '/CalendarManager/Findall',
            method: 'GET',
            extraParams: {
                custom_param1: 'customerName',
                custom_param2: 'description'
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                element.qtip({
                    content: event.custom_param1,
                    content: event.custom_param2
                });
            }
        },
```

UPDATE: 12/24/2020

To answer questions below.. I am using 5.3.2 version. I can use this as well and it will bring back everything but the custom parameters.

```
events: '/CalendarManager/Findall',
```

I am using Json pulling from DB - Below is the code..

```
    public ActionResult FindAll()
    {
        return Json(db.GetEvents.AsEnumerable().Select(e => new
        {
            id = e.CompanyId,
            companyName = e.CompanyName,
            title = e.Title,
            description = e.Description,
            allDay = e.AllDay,
            start = e.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
            end = e.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
            color = e.Color
        }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I changed the version I was using and that is when the extras did not show up. So I added what I thought the documentation said to use.

Adding the extra Params after the url did not work..

UPDATE:
I read through the suggested. I guess I am still not understanding or maybe not getting "Where I am supposed to put the code".

I believe I need to use `eventContent`. I also did use the `console.log(info.event.extendedProps.companyName);` Which is great, it does show up in the console window, However i need it on the calendar not in the console window. FullCalendar's examples could be a little better!

Here is what I did but still does not show on the calendar.

```
        eventDidMount: function (info) {
            var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                placement: 'top',
                trigger: 'hover',
                container: 'body'
            });
            console.log(info.event.extendedProps.companyName);
        },
        eventSources: [{
            url: '/CalendarManager/Findall',
            failure: function () {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
        }],
        eventContent: function (arg) {
           html: arg.event.extendedProps.companyName
        }
```

I did add some stuff in there to produce just a bubble when hovered over with this info but it does not work either.

Thank You!

UPDATE: 12/27/2020 Working Code

```
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        //Random default events
        //events: '/CalendarManager/Findall',
        
        eventDidMount: function (info) {
            var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                placement: 'top',
                trigger: 'hover',
                container: 'body'
            });
            console.log(info.event.extendedProps.companyName);
        },
        events: {
            url: '/CalendarManager/Findall',
            failure: function () {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
        },
        eventContent: function (arg) {
            return { html: arg.event.title + '<br>' + arg.event.extendedProps.companyName + '<br>' + arg.event.extendedProps.description };
        }
       
    });

    calendar.render();
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: are you sure that `events` is object? because in `FullCalendar` docs they are using array.

Comment: `extraParams` is for **sending to** the server, not **receiving from** it (I suggest you re-read the documentation if you were confused). Therefore these properties will not exist in your event data. If you want custom properties in your event data, then you should add them at the server side before you return the JSON. And also, eventRender doesn't exist in the latest fullCalendar. Please always tag the question with the exact fullCalendar version you are using, as there are substantial differences between the versions. The answer below has more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the update.... You say `it will bring back everything but the custom parameters.`...yes, because the custom parameters are what you are **sending**. They don't come back, they **go**. And your FindAll() method accepts no incoming parameters so it isn't expecting them.

Comment: So then the question becomes, how do i show the custom parameters that are already in the json string?

Comment: Ok, first please read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object  and make sure you understand what it says about non-standard fields at the end of the article. Next please read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks - this is the functionality which replaces eventRender in version 5 of fullCalendar. Try and implement something to solve your problem based on this information. If you still get stuck after that, edit your question to show your updated code. (P.s. you don't need customParams at all here as far as I can see, so you can just remove that from your events definition).

Comment: Your eventContent doesn't work because you didn't return anything from the function. Here's a working demo using a companyName field: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/oNzoKpo . Note the "return" keyword. I think you've read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection and conflated the static-object syntax with the callback syntax - but they are two separate ways of using that option. The examples do show that, if you look carefully.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you that works, However I would like to show Title, companyName, and description. I tried comma's in between them as well as 3 separate returns. The seperate returns only shows the first and then seperated by commas with 1 return, returns only the last in the string..

Comment: Glad you got it working, but...if you found a solution, please add it to the **answers** section of this page, below. This is a question-and-answer site. The answer is not part of the question! And you are allowed and encouraged to answer your own questions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, let me know what kind of version of `fullcalendar` you are using.
[fullcalendar v5.5 doesn't provide `eventRender`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4).

[image]

And `extraParams` is not what you want to show. It is the query params which attach after the request url, like `http://example.com/CalendarManager/Findall?custom_param1=customerName&...`.

If you want to use extend event props then you should [parse them](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing) as `extendProps`.

And you should use [Event Render Hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) rather than `eventRender` if you are using the latest version.

**How to fix:**

1. Anyway, you should use `function`, not an object.

You can use [events (as a function)](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function)

```
function( fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback ) { }
```

You can also use [events (as a json feed)](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed)

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: '/myfeed.php'
});
```

2. If you are going to use `object` rather than `function`, then you can use [`eventSources`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources)

And if you want to handle the success response, then use [`eventSourceSuccess` function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSourceSuccess)

**Here is an example (using fullcalendar v5.5):**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'listWeek',
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $("#dashboard-calendar-column .pre-loader").show();
            } else {
                $("#dashboard-calendar-column .pre-loader").hide();
            }
        },
        // get all events from the source
        eventSources: [{
            url: '/CalendarManager/Findall',
            method: 'GET',

            failure: function() {
                document.getElementById('script-warning').style.display = 'block'
            }
        }],
         // convert the response to the fullcalendar events
         eventSourceSuccess: function(content, xhr) {
            var events = [];

            content.events.value.map(event => {
                events.push({
                    id: event.id,
                    allDay: event.isAllDay,
                    title: event.subject,
                    start:event.start.dateTime,
                    end: event.end.dateTime,
                    // The followings are what you want to add as extended
                    custom_param1: 'customerName',
                    custom_param2: 'description',
                    // Or you could add them to the extendedProps object
                    extendedProps: {
                        custom_param1: 'customerName',
                        custom_param2: 'description',
                        description: event.bodyPreview,
                        ...
                    },
                    // You can check fullcalendar event parsing
                    ...
                })
            })

            return events;
        },
        eventDidMount: function (arg) {
            // remove dot between the event titles
            $(arg.el).find('.fc-list-event-graphic').remove();

           
            // You can select the extended props like arg.event.custom_param1 or arg.event.extendProps.custom_param1
            ...
        },
    });

    calendar.render();
})
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extraParams` using `eventSources` if you are using fullcalendar v5.

```
    eventSources: [{
        url: '/CalendarManager/Findall',
        method: 'POST',
        extraParams: {
            custom_param1: 'customerName',
            custom_param2: 'description'
        }
        ...
    }]
```

You should use `POST` rather use `GET`, then it will work.